# adb command not found when running it from Android Studio terminal in Linux Mint

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint Cinnamon, version 21.3. I just wanted to practice running the adb command from the command line in Android Studio Hedgehog (2023.1.1 patch 2), but I keep getting `sh: adb: command not found` whenever I type any adb command.

I ran `sudo apt install adb`, and it's been installed in `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools`. I see the adb executable in there.

Then, I went to `File Settings->Tools->Terminal` in Android Studio,

[image: Terminal Settings Start Directory]

and I set the Start Directory to `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools`. It did not make a difference. I wonder if I need to change the Android SDK location to this, but I feel hesitant to disrupt some of these defaults, being a relative newcomer to Android Studio. Also, Android Studio doesn't even see this directory; I pasted it in there, but it's impossible to actually navigate to it, as it's invisible from Android Studio. I set the $PATH environment variable to include the platform-tools folder, and it does, but I wonder if there is another $PATH variable that's specific to Android Studio, and whether there's a PATH subsystem in the IDE itself that's not related to what I set up in my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting ANDROID_HOME (key) pointing to `/usr/lib/android-sdk` (`Environment Variables` field). You *may* need to exit/re-start Android Studio for this to take effect).
PS: Did you do a `sudo apt install adb` as the current user (vs some other root account)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I did run ```sudo apt install adb``` as the current user. I tried setting the ANDROID_HOME variable via terminal using the ```setenv ANDROID_HOME /usr/lib/android-sdk``` command, but I got a "bad command" message back, and I am speculating it's for the same reasons I am getting that same error when I type in ```adb logcat```. Do I need to change the path through the UI itself and go to Tools...SDK and change it there? It's currently pointing to a directory under my home directory, not to ```/usr/lib/android-sdk```. Is that the value I should change?

Answer (score 0):

I did get it to work after I added a couple of export lines to my .bashrc file (`sudo nano ~/.bashrc` to make changes. Then CTRL+O to save and `source ~/.bashrc` to load the file):

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Then, I went to File..Terminal in Android Studio and looked at the Shell Path text box. It had `/bin/sh` shell which means that the Android Studio was using sh shell, while I was using bash. I changed it to `/bin/bash`. I restarted the Android Studio, and the adb command started to work!

One thing I also did, which I do not know whether it helped or not was to go to Tools...SDK Manager in Android Studio and pick the "SDK Tools" tab. I noticed that Android SDK Command-Line Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools weren't installed, so I installed them. This was the first thing I did in order to attempt to fix the problem, but this step by itself didn't fix anything. The adb utility had already been installed on my system prior to checking the command line and platform tools checkboxes, but this step might have helped in conjunction with the other two.